# Example of nested resets in Scala

Tags: scala, reset, continuations

This is a question about Scala continuations. Can `resets` be nested? If they can: what are nested `resets` useful for ? Is there any example of nested `resets`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `reset`s can be nested, and, yes, it can be useful.  As an example, I recently prototyped an API for the [scalagwt project](http://code.google.com/p/scalagwt/) that would allow GWT developers to write asynchronous RPCs (remote procedure calls) in a direct style (as opposed to the callback-passing style that is used in GWT for Java). For example:

```
field1 = "starting up..."                   // 1 
field2 = "starting up..."                   // 2 
async {                                     // (reset)
   val x = service.someAsyncMethod()        // 3 (shift)
   field1 = x                               // 5 
   async {                                  // (reset)
      val y = service.anotherAsyncMethod()  // 6 (shift)
      field2 = y                            // 8 
   } 
   field2 = "waiting..."                    // 7 
} 
field1 = "waiting..."                       // 4
```

The comments indicate the order of execution.  Here, the `async` method performs a `reset`, and each service call performs a `shift` (you can see the implementation on [my github fork](https://github.com/anovstrup/scalagwt-sample), specifically [Async.scala](https://github.com/anovstrup/scalagwt-sample/blob/progress-gwtdlx-hosted/src/com/google/gwt/sample/gwtdlx/client/Async.scala)).

Note how the nested `async` changes the control flow.  Without it, the line `field2 = "waiting"` would not be executed until after successful completion of the second RPC.

When an RPC is made, the implementation captures the continuation *up to the inner-most `async` boundary*, and suspends it for execution upon successful completion of the RPC. Thus, the nested `async` block allows control to flow immediately to the line after it as soon as the second RPC is made. Without that nested block, on the other hand, the continuation would extend all the way to the end of the outer `async` block, in which case all the code within the outer `async` would block on each and every RPC.

Answer (score 1):

`reset` forms an abstraction so that code outside is not affected by the fact that the code inside is implemented with continuation magic. So if you're writing code with reset and shift, it can call other code which may or may not be implemented with reset and shift as well. In this sense they can be nested.